# set c_char_p in Python

Tags: python, pointers, header-files, ctypes

In the C header file I have:

```
long test_API callAndSave(   
    ___OUT_ char param1[31], 
    ___OUT_ char param2[5], 
    ___OUT_ char param3[21], 
    ___OUT_ char* pointerParam
    );
```

I am trying to set and pass all the parameters in the `Python` and pass them to `callAndSave`:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./testlib.so')

param1 = (ctypes.c_char*31)()
param2 = (ctypes.c_char*5)()
param3 = (ctypes.c_char*21)()
pointerParam = ctypes.c_char_p()

lib.eftTrx(param1,param2,param3,pointerParam)
```

But I am getting "`output parameter is NULL`" error for `pointerParam`. How should I define "`___OUT_ char* pointerParam`" in Python correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
___OUT_ char* pointerParam
```

The `___OUT_` in the specification generally means that this pointer will have data written to it. So you must allocate a buffer to write to. `ctypes.c_char_p()` doesn't make a buffer - it's just a null pointer.

Look into [**`ctypes.create_string_buffer`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=create_string_buffer#ctypes.create_string_buffer). You must figure out yourself how big of a buffer `callAndSave` expects.